# Help with this comments in this number theory book

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to understand this comment in Niven's number theory book page 50:

[image]

I need help with the converse, i.e., if no two integers in the set of $m$ integers are congruent modulo $m$, then this set forms a complete residue system modulo $m$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/pigeon.shtml

Comment: @labbhattacharjee can you help me how to applied this principle?

Comment: We have $m$ possible residues representation $m$ holes/buckets . If no two are congruent, they can not  be placed in the same bucket. So, each bucket will contain exactly one residue

Comment: @labbhattacharjee your solution is perfectly fine, but you use implicitly equivalence classes and partitions.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee we don't know so far that each $x_i$ represents an equivalence class and each equivalence class is disjoint from each other.

Answer (score 1):

The usual proof of the converse requires [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division).  Since the remainder is an integer in the interval $[0,m-1]$, the set of $m$ incongruent integers in your set must exactly cover all possibilities.

The proof for this relies on the notion that any one-to-one function from a finite set to another of the same cardinality, must in fact be onto.  The domain is your test set, the codomain is $\{1,2,\ldots, m\}$, and the function is congruence.